# Multiple if statements- all or nothing?

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement

I'm trying to load specific values, out of what will someday be a larger JSON response (videos on Wistia). For now, it only has two videos (slatwall.mp4 & igoodworks.mp4) and their respective data as seen in the json [HERE](https://api.wistia.com/v1/projects/7mal1h1pl4.json?api_password=4270cfa9ee6a62203fd09f42bc342125e2187151bff16242df2055a6e4241714).

The javascript below works great *if both of the `v.name` values exist. But, if you change `slatwall.mp4` to something else, neither `if` statements work, and the `else` statement is called.. even though `igoodworks.mp4` exists.

Javascript (JSFiddle is also below):

```
var projectUrl = "https://api.wistia.com/v1/projects/7mal1h1pl4.json?api_password=<api password>"

$.getJSON(projectUrl, function (data) {

$('#thumb').show();
$('#thumb2').show();

$.each(data.medias, function (i, v) {

    var thumb_orig = v.thumbnail.url;
    var thumb_size = "640x360";
    var thumb = thumb_orig.replace('100x60', thumb_size);
    var duration = v.duration;
    var name = v.name;
    var created = v.created;
    var status = v.status;

    if (v.name == "slatwall.mp4") {
        $('#thumb').attr('src', thumb);
        $('#duration').text(duration + " seconds long");
        $('#status').text(name);
        return;
    } 
    if (v.name == "igoodworks.mp4") {
        $('#thumb2').attr('src', thumb);
        $('#duration2').text(duration + " seconds long");
        $('#status2').text(name);
        return;
    } else {
        $('body').html('No Videos Found');
    }
    })
});
```

Any help what I'm trying to accomplish?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/motioncrafter/7r4smh9h/7/)

Comment: You probably want `else if (v.name == "igoodworks.mp4") {`

Comment: BTW, you are exposing some API password!

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration that doesn't find a match, it changes the whole body of the document to ´No Videos Found´.  On subsequent iterations, the IDs you're targetting (`thumb2`, etc) don't exist any more.

A cleaner way to approach this is to assemble the content dynamically.  Get rid of the hard-coded `divs`, and change the callback function to something like this:

```
function (data) {
    var found = false;
    $.each(data.medias, function (i, v) {
        found = true;
        var thumb_orig = v.thumbnail.url;
        var thumb_size = "640x360";
        var thumb = thumb_orig.replace('100x60',thumb_size);
        var duration = v.duration;
        var name = v.name;
        var created = v.created;
        var status = v.status;

        $('body').append('<img src="' + thumb + '"/>').append('<div>' + duration + ' seconds long</div>').append('<div>' + name + '</div>');
    })

    if (!found) {
        $('body').html('No Videos Found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can reuse your code (just add `1` to your first set elements ids). Than you can check if `$.inArray(v.name, namesArray) !== -1` to know if name is valid. That way you can have infinite videos and don't have to re-write same code.

To check if all videos was found, just count how much videos was `inArray` and compare it with total number of videos (Not really understood what must happen when some video are not found; **In `$.each` `return false` means `break` and `return true` means `continue`**.

Also consider re-formatting your HTML to get rid of IDs: dynamic content creation, dynamic elements selection, etc.

```js
var names = [
  'slatwall.mp4',
  'igoodworks.mp4'
];

var totalFound = 0;
var index = 0;
var total = 0;

data = {
  "id": 2014528,
  "name": "Vipheo Uploads",
  "mediaCount": 2,
  "created": "2015-11-03T23:36:48+00:00",
  "updated": "2015-11-04T06:57:06+00:00",
  "hashedId": "7mal1h1pl4",
  "anonymousCanUpload": false,
  "anonymousCanDownload": false,
  "public": true,
  "publicId": "7mal1h1pl4",
  "description": "\n",
  "medias": [{
    "id": 16565434,
    "name": "igoodworks.mp4",
    "type": "Video",
    "created": "2015-11-04T05:49:46+00:00",
    "updated": "2015-11-04T06:57:02+00:00",
    "duration": 65.152,
    "hashed_id": "87bwf7o64z",
    "description": "",
    "progress": 1.0,
    "status": "ready",
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/cc0fc1451586501156eeec7625914e9d210226b5.jpg?image_crop_resized=100x60",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 60
    }
  }, {
    "id": 16561778,
    "name": "slatwall.mp4",
    "type": "Video",
    "created": "2015-11-03T23:40:16+00:00",
    "updated": "2015-11-04T06:57:06+00:00",
    "duration": 61.808,
    "hashed_id": "q0ynu4iasa",
    "description": "",
    "progress": 1.0,
    "status": "ready",
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/90b9231d07e0f49219b0b7fc5c39afa07d2542f1.jpg?image_crop_resized=100x60",
      "width": 100,
      "height": 60
    }
  }]
};

$.each(data.medias, function(k, v) {
  index++;

  if ($.inArray(v.name, names) !== -1) {
    var thumb_orig = v.thumbnail.url;
    var thumb_size = "640x360";
    var thumb = thumb_orig.replace('100x60', thumb_size);
    var duration = v.duration;
    var name = v.name;
    var created = v.created;
    var status = v.status;

    totalFound++;

    $('#thumb' + index).attr('src', thumb);
    $('#duration' + index).text(duration + " seconds long");
    $('#status' + index).text(name);
  }
});

if (totalFound != index || index == 1) {
  alert('Videos not found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a id="thumb1"></a>
  <span id="duration1"></span>
  <span id="status1"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a id="thumb2"></a>
  <span id="duration2"></span>
  <span id="status2"></span>
</div>
```